# Selenium---can't click on an image

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have this function and i am not able to click on all of the magnifying glasses from a page. I have tried until now, by using different alternatives. What is commented, is what i tried until now.

```
def lupa():

    elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[onclick='return Go(event, 2)'] > img[title='Details']")
for element in elements:
    #element.click()
    element.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Please see below how looks the HTML code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return Go(event, 2)">
                 <img title="Details" src="/common/images/Detail.gif">
</a>
```

This are the old XPATHs i used in order to click on the image.

```
 #browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr[17]/td[11]/a[2]/img").click()
        #lupa = browser.find_element(By.XPATH("//img[@src='/common/images/Detail.gif']"))
        #lupa = browser.find_element(By.cssSelector("a[src='/common/images/Detail.gif']"))
        #lupe = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[src='/common/images/Detail.gif']"))
        #lupa=browser.find_element_by_link_text("Details").click()
        #lupa= browser.find_element_by_id("Details").click()
        #elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[src='/common/images/Detail.gif']"))
```

Thank you for your answer!

Cohen

Comment: Last error i got while using elements = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH("//img[@src='/common/images/Detail.gif']"))  -----TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Share exception you get with your current code

Comment: what do u mean? u want to see the error i got while running my code?

Comment: Yep. With this code `elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[src='/common/images/Detail.gif']"))` `for element in elements:
        element.click()`

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: JeffC will edit the post tommorow. i am on mobile and is midnight in my country

Answer (score 1):

Most of the locators you tried aren't valid. You probably should spend some time learning about the different locator types and how they work.

Given the HTML, the CSS selector below should find the `IMG` tag(s) you want.

```
img[title='Details']
```

Another thing, you are not using implicit wait correctly. It's set once for the life of the driver. Calling it over and over does nothing. You don't want to use implicit wait, use an explicit wait instead. Look at some tutorials for `WebDriverWait`.

---

EDIT: Clicking the `IMG` tag should work just find since it's surrounded by the desired `A` tag. But... if you need to click the `A` tag specifically, you should be able to use the locators below.

More specific CSS selector

```
a[onclick='return Go(event, 2)'] > img[title='Details']
```

XPath

```
//a[@onclick='return Go(event, 2)'][./img[title='Details']]
```

Comment: Thank you jeffC! I have changed my post and my code. I think that is working, but no event is created. When i click on the magnifying glass basicaly i open the details of a case. Is like epxanding the information from a case. The driver i think that is clickinging the image, but is not expanding the case. I got no error in my terminal tough...what is wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure because I can't see the site. Perhaps you are clicking the wrong element? Maybe the HTML you provided isn't the element you want to click? Share a link to the page and we can take a look.

Comment: It's best if you edit the question and add this info so that it's easier for everyone to see it (and format).

Comment: done! there is like a java script that is enabled when clicking in and near the mirror glass. and i need to click on that javascript event 2.

Comment: Clicking the `IMG` tag should work just fine, if it's the right one, since it is enveloped by the desired `A` tag. Have you tested to make sure that the locator is getting the right `IMG`?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple new locators to try based on the additional HTML.

Comment: thank you Jeff! when i used the css version i got no error but still no event was created, i think this is due to the fact that i click on that...is there  a way instead of clicking to call that procedure or event? when i used the xpath i got an error _img[title='Details']]"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable_.   Thank you for your help!

Comment: The CSS selector is clicking on the `IMG`, it's just more specific in case there was more than one element on the page that matched that locator. It looks like the error from the XPath was cut off... what's the complete error message?

Comment: You can call the JS function directly using JSE but I wouldn't get in the habit of doing that.